# Remove extra space under datatable HTML widgets in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

I'm creating an html report with rmarkdown that has some interactive tables generated by the `DT::datatable()` function and for some of them there is extra whitespace under the table which makes the formatting of the report look a little off and so far I have been unable to get rid of it.

This is what the spacing looks like normally between the datatable and the next plot:

[image]

This is what the spacing looks like with the extra space:

[image]

It seems to only be happening with tables that have a small number of rows (<5) which made me suspect its holding the space for a table with a minimum of 10 rows. Based on this, I tried setting the datatable options `pageLength = 5` and  `lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20)` and also tried `fillContainer = FALSE` but nothing so far has worked.

The code to generate the tables and plots directly under is shown below and is called from a separate function because I'm creating a large number of tables in addition to other plots with different inputs each time. The plot is a ggplot object.

```
model_obj$data  %>%
  DT::datatable(extensions = 'Buttons',
                options = list(dom = 'Blfrtip',
                               buttons = c('excel'))) %>%
  knitr::knit_print() %>%
  cat()
  
cat("\n\n#### Title \n\n")
print(model_obj$plot1)
```

Comment: It seems the space is being reserved for the table, as you suspect. It's difficult to assess the problem with the code provided. You may have more luck getting help if you share a reproducible example.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Please provide a reproducible example.